# How to lock mysql tables in php

Tags: php, mysql

How do I lock mysql tables in php? I currently have this code:

```
$db->query("LOCK TABLES tbl_othercharge WRITE");
for($x=0;$x<=500; $x++){
    $id = get_max();
    $db->query("INSERT INTO tbl_othercharge SET tblocID = '$id', assessmentID='lock1'");
}

$db->query("UNLOCK TABLES");
```

Here's the get_max() function, which obviously will fail if the script above executes simultaneously.

```
 <?php
    function get_max(){
        global $db;
        $max = $db->get_var("SELECT MAX(tblocNumber) FROM tbl_othercharge");
        if($max == null){
            $max = 1;
        }else if($max >= 1){
            $max = $max + 1;
        }
        return 'OC'.$max;
    }
    ?>
```

I'm trying to test if there are still concurrency problems by executing the same script on 2 browsers.
The script above inserts 400+ records instead of 999 records. How do I properly lock the table while I'm inserting something into it.

I want to lock the table to prevent something like this to happen:
[image]

As you can see the field with the prefix 'OC' on it should have a number which is equal to the auto-increment primary key.

Comment: And why would you want to lock the table?

Comment: What about InnoDB storage engine and transactions?

Comment: 999 records? Your loop stops at 500.

Comment: @PiTheNumber : 1000 I should say, because if I execute it simultaneously it should yield 1000 records.

Comment: @KyokaSuigetsu If your real problem here is producing unique ID's tied to the auto increment value, you might find a useful alternative approach [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8021084).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The only reliable solution is to do an insert with a dummy value, getting the last insert id, and updating the row to the correct value.

```
mysql_query("INSERT INTO table (field) VALUES (dummy);");
$id = mysql_last_insert_id();
mysql_query("UPDATE table SET field='OC{$id}' WHERE id={$id} LIMIT 1;");
```

Answer (score 3):

I'd suggest to drop the 'OC' field from the table, e.g.

```
CREATE TABLE tbl_othercharge (tblocID int AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY, assessmentID varchar(100));

CREATE VIEW vw_othercharge SELECT tblocID, concat('OC',tblocID) as OCnumber, assessmentID FROM tbl_othercharge
```

now direct all relevant SELECTs to vw_othercharge and forget about it.

Answer (score 2):

Have you try:

```
for($x=0;$x<=500; $x++){
    $db->query("LOCK TABLES tbl_othercharge WRITE");
    $id = get_max();
    $db->query("INSERT INTO tbl_othercharge SET tblocID = '$id', assessmentID='lock1'");
    $db->query("UNLOCK TABLES");
}
```

In this way you will set lock each time you insert a row!