# MySql "For Update" results in Error

Tags: mysql, select, sql-update

A new project has forced me to lock a table while updates are processed.  I have followed every suggestion and guide I can find, including [How to lock mysql tables in php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8576125/how-to-lock-mysql-tables-in-php) and 
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/innodb-locking-reads.html, but I always get the same error: *#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'LIMIT 0, 30' at line 1*

In order to get past any possible demons in my live table, I created a new table on the INNODB engine for testing, added the unique index, inserted a few rows, and used the following syntax to query:

```
SELECT svalue FROM `test` WHERE skey='key2' for update;
```

which produces the same error.  Removing the **for update;** from the query allows the query to run without error.

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong, and have tried everything I can think of. Please help me understand what I'm missing!

Thanks

Comment: I experience the same error, even when wrapping the statement in a transaction. My server is 10.4.10-MariaDB

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most of the time, MySQL will handle table or row locking when you are using transactions (InnoDB-typed).

```
//Doing transactions
mysql_query("SET AUTOCOMMIT=0");
mysql_query("START TRANSACTION");
$query = "SELECT svalue FROM `test` WHERE skey='key2'";

if($query)
{
  mysql_query("COMMIT");
}else{
  mysql_query("ROLLBACK");
}
```

Comment: My goal is to select an existing value from the table, then increment and update it while making sure another process doesn't read the old value before the update is complete. Most of my research pointed to "For Update" for this scenario, is there an advantage to using transactions instead?

Comment: @foxns7: op is actually correct to lock the row. A concurrent transaction could modify it.

Answer (score 0):

Locking outside of a transaction is mostly meaningless. This probably explains the syntax error.

Btw, if you're merely seeking to increment a column's value (your comment), just update it directly:

```
update tbl set col = col + 1 where ...
```

Comment: The problem I'm running into is that I need to the know the new value the col was updated to.  I haven't been able to find an "Update and return value" statement like Postgres has.  And I was trying to follow the code on the dev.mysql.com page listed in my question, which shows this example:  SELECT counter_field FROM child_codes FOR UPDATE;
UPDATE child_codes SET counter_field = counter_field + 1;  Do I need to wrap this in a transaction, is this my problem?

Comment: Yep, that is likely the problem. As an aside, if you know Postgres well enough to be aware of update returning, is there a particular reason you want to get back into MySQL? :-)

Comment: Unfortunately MySQL isn't my choice on this particular project... always beholden to "the powers that be".