# Get Lock on MySql table from PHP Script

Tags: php, mysql, mutual-exclusion

I have several users trying to access a table, using PHP script, concurrently.

Here is some code:

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT ID FROM usersPark
    WHERE isSharing = '1' and email != '$email' and isBooked != 1")
```

Now, if $result is not empty I need to set isBooked = 1 like this:

```
UPDATE `usersPark` SET `isBooked` = 1,` WHERE ID = ...
```

I think, I need to acquire a lock at the very beginning of the script, before the first query. How can I get a lock?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to lock mysql tables in php](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8576125/how-to-lock-mysql-tables-in-php)

Answer (score 0):

If your table is using InnoDB, then this supports two types of locking reads that you can use for this.

You'll probably want to use `SELECT ... FOR UPDATE` - or something similar. I could write about it here, but the MySQL documentation is rather good on this, so check that out [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/innodb-locking-reads.html).