# Splitting of string in not happening. I am trying with str_split() function

Tags: php, mysql, html, sql

I am stuck with a small problem in PHP with string function. I'm fetching last row value from the emp_id column. This gives me 1mw112 and this is a correct result. What I want actually to increment it automatically which is not possible because of this 
emp_id is mixed of characters and numbers. What I can try to do now is to split this 
value into two parts ( 1mw and 112 ). If this is possible then I can store 112 in another variable and can easily increment by 1 manually and while inserting in to the table; I can display it in readonly format in a form. I've tried `str_split($var,3)`, but is not working.

This is what m trying with:

```
<?php
    $db=mysql_connect("localhost","m","m");// database connection
    mysql_select_db("mars",$db); // database selection

    //$query1="SELECT LAST(eid) AS eid FROM emp_info" ;

    $query1="SELECT eid FROM emp_info ORDER BY eid DESC LIMIT 1"; // sql query to select last value from the column
    $result=mysql_query($query1);

    while($record=mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
    {
        while(each($record))
        {
            $eid=$record['eid'];
        }
    }

    echo $eid;
    echo "<br>";
    $splitted=str_split($eid,-2);
    echo $splitted;
?>
```

This is echoing "array" as an output.

Can anyone please help me out to store last 3 digits in an another variable?

Comment: It echoes "array" because it is an array. Try `print_r($splitted)` instead to see the split result

Comment: Thanks for a quick response. This is the output m getting with print_r. Array ( [0] => 1m [1] => w1 [2] => 12 ). But actually I just want to have last 3 digits in an another variable.

Comment: @ShashiRoy You don't need to do this at all, you can just increment `$eid` - see my answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$splitted` is an array, which means you have to iterate through the array to get the values of it.

In your case, you could do this, instead::

```
$splitted = str_split($eid, 3);
$splitted[1]++;

$eid = implode("", $splitted);
echo $eid;
```

This will enable you to get the result you wan't as long as eid follows the same format.

**UPDATE**
To answer the question that came in the comment, another solution could be this:

```
$eid = "1mv112";

$splitted = explode("mv", $eid);
$splitted[1]++;

$eid = implode("mv", $splitted);
echo $eid;
```

Comment: suppose my last 3 digits becomes 4 digits in case number of employees increases in the database in that case? sorry for the simple question. m still new to it. thanks indavance .

Comment: Then str_split wouldn't be the right way to go. It really depends on what format you have. If the format always would be something like 1mw[number], substr() or explode() could do the trick. But if the last three digits becomes four instead, the answer you accepted won't work anymore either.

Comment: Yours code is perfect even if last 3 digits becomes 4 digits. According to the format "1mv" will remain same and nly last digits will keep incrementing according to the number of employees. Thanks a lot for very very quick response. You guys always rocks. Thanks a lot.  :)

Answer (score 4):

You want to use substr() function here not str_split().  Using str_split() returns an array with each character of the string populating each element of the array.

```
<?php

$str = '1mw112';

echo substr($str, -3);

?>
```

http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.substr.php

Answer (score 2):

There is a fundamental flaw in your reasoning for needing to do this:

> What I want actually to increment it automatically which is not possible because of this emp_id is mixed of characters and numbers.

This is not true. Consider the following:

```
<?php

  $str = '1mw112';
  echo $str; // 1mw112
  $str++;
  echo $str; // 1mw113
```

Comment: First of all thanks for the response and sorry for the confusion. I actually wanted it to be incremented automatically in the table column. And table does not allow me to make it primary key and can not do auto increment with varchar.

Comment: Actually it can be done by creating a PK across two columns - I had a similar issue to this, and you may find a nice answer to your problem on [one of my old questions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8021084). I used a combination of the accepted answer and the answer from Adrian Cornish. Even so, if you are going to increment the value in PHP, the solution above works and is much simpler than messing about splitting the string up.

Answer (score 1):

try this :

```
$var = substr($eid, 3);
```

;)

Answer (score 0):

you can just simply use `substr()` in the fallowing way

```
$lastDigits = substr($eid, -3);
```