# How can I show a 2 column mysql composite primary key value as a default value in a 3rd column?

Tags: mysql, default, composite-primary-key

I can not find this any where (I am probably not asking the right questions). Would someone please point me in the right direction.

I am using a 2 column composite primary key in MySQL. 
I would like to display that value as a default value in a 3rd column in the same table and in another table.

```
Col_1 value = ABC, 
Col_2 value = 123, 
PK          = ABC123, 

Col_3 default value = ABC123
```

Would anyone be able to explain how to do this?

I would prefer not to do this with a trigger or an insert statement if possible.

Thanks,

Ted

Comment: Have you considered [`CONCAT()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/string-functions.html#function_concat)?

Comment: Hi Ami, thanks for the reply. How would I use CONCAT as a default?

Comment: See Kevin's answer. I thought you meant in code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There aren't many situations where you *really need* the value to actually be in the column. You can get the same effect many times by creating the value in the select statement you use to fetch the data -- or in the php, ruby or whatever code you use to display the data.

For example:

```
SELECT Col_1, Col_2, CONCAT(NEW.Col_1,NEW.Col_2) as Col_3
FROM my_table;
```

This will resolve the issue for you while avoiding triggers and other fancy sql tricks.

I think this is a better approach as well in case someone wants to change the values of Col_1 or Col_2 -- if they change one of those values, then a column that held the combination of the two would also have to be updated. It makes things more complex than they need to be.

If you have some reason they *must* be in the database table, let us know.

Comment: Hi Kevin, Thanks for the reply. I am using this PK as a unique memberID for a web app people will be using on their hand-helds. They will initially sign up when they are online using a simple PHP form. They will supply the ABC part and MySQL will supply an auto_increment part to make it unique. Once the entire PK is created it will be passed to the hand-held and stored as their memberID on the SQLite DB on the hand-held. If I do not create the complete PK somewhere how can I pass it to the hand-held? In 2 parts?

Comment: I see now what you are doing. I believe you can still push the key to the handheld using something like `SELECT CONCAT(NEW.Col_1,'-',NEW.Col_2) as the_key FROM my_table;` and then send it back to them. (Notice I added a hyphen '-' to make it easy to break the key back into pieces.) This has the added benefit of allowing you to keep primary key as only the Integer portion -- it will make accessing the data much faster. Then when the handheld sends you the key later, you simply break it apart in your code by splitting on the '-' and look up the two pieces.

Comment: Kevin, I am having trouble getting my head around your idea. If you are interested you can take a look at this post, the accepted answer, as to how I am trying to create the memberID. [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8021084/how-to-get-next-alpha-numeric-id-based-on-existing-value-from-mysql.) Thanks for your help. I will keep trying to catch up. The speed is not a major concern as the DB will never grow above 20K. The way I understand it the auto increment value will not be unique. EG 'abc001, abc002, def001, def002 etc.'

Answer (score 0):

Use trigger. I haven't tested this yet but it's worth for you to try.

```
CREATE TRIGGER `auto_default` 
BEFORE INSERT ON `table` FOR EACH ROW 
SET NEW.Col_3=CONCAT(NEW.Col_1,NEW.Col_2);
```

Comment: Hello Jonas, Thanks for taking the time to reply. I thought there might be a simpler way than using triggers. Any other ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I have not come across this . Probably you will have to use a trigger(you indicate this is not your choice)  or has to build it into the application that does the Insert into the table .

When I scan through the material of MYSQL , it cleary states that "the default value must be a constant; it cannot be a function or an expression" .

For reference "http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/data-type-defaults.html"

For using a trigger the trigger sugested by Jonas should work ..

Comment: Hi payyans, I have read the page you refer to. The PK will be a constant. The only thing that makes this request different is that the constant value is coming from 2 columns, so I figured there must be a way to do this easily. You suggest ..."build it into the application that does the Insert into the table" ... I have done a similar thing in SQLite referencing a javascript variable as I use JS to create the tables, which works great. Is this the type of thing you have in mind, maybe with PHP?